# Trying to find the manual for a Sokkia GIR1000

Tags: gps

I'm trying to track down a manual for a Sokkia GIR1000.  My department has one but over the years the manual seems to have disappeared.  Does anyone have one or know where I can get one?

Comment: Have you asked Sokkia?

Answer (score 1):

Since Sokkia is now owned by Topcon, you may have to go to the Topcon website, and search their archives.

That unit may also be a re-branded Ashtech model, possibly named the Reliance, since Ashtech (Javad Ashjaee) partnered up with Topcon for a while.

Comment: Yeah I have sent in a request with Topcon for the manual, no luck there yet.  

But I didn't know about the Ashtech thing.  I'll look into that.  I appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome!
I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Upon further digging, the GIR 1000 may actually be an Ashtech SCA-12.
There is a 142 page PDF manual that I did not peruse, but it is from Ashtech which at the time was affiliated with Magellan, and Topcon.